# DISQUS Shows 0 Comments With Trailing Slash

Tags: wordpress, disqus

Site: http://www.grmdaily.com

I'm on WP and the shortcode is  which throws something like this out

```
<a data-disqus-identifier="MyIdent-76568" class="disqus-comment-count" href="http://myurl.com/a-post-title/#disqus_thread"></a>
```

However this always shows 0. If I remove the final forward slash, it then shows the correct number

Please advise!

**UPDATE**

The function is now as follows which removes the trailing slash

```
function disqus_count( $disqus_shortname ) {
    // $disqus_shortname = isset( $disqus_shortname ) ? $disqus_shortname : 'grmdailywpstaging';
    wp_enqueue_script('disqus_count','http://'.$disqus_shortname.'.disqus.com/count.js');
    echo '<a data-disqus-identifier="'.$disqus_shortname.'-'.get_the_ID().'" class="disqus-comment-count" href="'. rtrim(get_permalink(),'/') .'#disqus_thread"></a>';
}
```

However no count is still shown. If I copy/paste the resulting code and stick it in manually, it then does work!

Not sure how/why

**UPDATE**

Got rid of

`wp_enqueue_script('disqus_count','http://'.$disqus_shortname.'.disqus.com/count.js');`

As the count.js script was already being called!

Comment: I advise you to leave out the trailing slash. Seriously though, what is your question, and what have you tried?

Comment: Made amends to my original question. Trailing slash removed but still doesn't work unless I do it manually